# Run two SKActions in sequence without SKAction.Sequence (make sure one finishes, wait then run the other)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to create 2 functions. One that moves a sprite (a car) along the y axis (up) and one that rotates it (left or right by 90 degrees). 
I created two functions (`moveCarForward()` and `rotateCar(angle))`that have almost the same code, with different actions inside.

```
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
            let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: angle, duration: 1)
            let doneAction = SKAction.run({ [weak self] in
                car?.removeAction(forKey: "carRotating")
            })
            let moveActionWithDone = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, rotateAction, doneAction])
            self.car!.run(moveActionWithDone, withKey: "carRotating")
```

Now my issue is that in my GameViewController, I want to be able to call the actions in any order I want. For example call (Go forward, rotate right, go forward, rotate left) but when I run the code the actions are done out of order (or at times if I do move forward twice, one is always ignored). I think this is because the run actions are executed asynchronously and so some start running before the other finish. I know Action Sequence are helpful here, but this is a functions tutorial for beginners and I need to be able to call each function separately from the ViewController. I tried using DispatchGroup() but it either blocks the main thread or keeps them running out of order (I am probably using them wrong). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of actions that fire on completion of the previous action.

In my example, I use a custom action to do this.

```
var car = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"car")
var actionChain = [SKAction]()
var completionAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration:0){
                           [node, elapsedTime] in
                           if self.actionChain.count == 0 || elapsedTime > 0 {return}
                           let action = self.actionChain.removeFirst()
                           node.run(SKAction.sequence([action, self.completionAction]))
                        }

func moveCarForward(){

     actionChain.append(SKAction.moveBy(x:10,y:0, duration:1))
}
func rotateCar(){

     actionChain.append(SKAction.rotate(byAngle:.pi, duration:1))
}

func driveCar(){
    car.run(completionAction)
}

func testPath(){
    moveCarForward()
    rotateCar()
    rotateCar()
    moveCarForward()
    driveCar()

}
```